# What is currently the more accepted Agreement Between Raters Statistics or most referenced paper?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

I found a question that is related [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34510/how-to-measure-agreement-between-a-set-of-raters), but it doesn't really goes on what I want to know.

I found a couple of papers using Kappa Statistic from 2006, and 2010, but afterwards I found other authors disagreeing with it like [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=kappa%20statistic%20is%20not%20satisfactory%20for%20assessing%20the%20extent%20of%20agreement%20between%20raters&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CFsQFjAA&url=http://www.agreestat.com/research_papers/kappa_statistic_is_not_satisfactory.pdf&ei=BkEyUK2vOofc0QHznoCIBA&usg=AFQjCNHmg3xdSrT3fOkwPw7plZl2wyIZLA&sig2=NLzgu37W42nNCIlLIndivQ) and [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27743223/201209-eacl2012-Kappa.pdf). I also noticed other tests being listed and suggested like the ICC on the question pointed on cross validated I pointed, and on the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability).

To narrow down the context: I have a set n of participants which consistently were asked to say 'yes/no/maybe' on a set of questions. I've seen authors also changing the yes/maybe to 'evidence' and converting it to yes/no by just summing the quantities of yes and maybe.

My questions thus are:

1. What is the most recent/accepted or referenced paper in respect to this discussion?
2. Given my dataset constraints, which test would be more appropriated? I was considering Fleiss but when I saw it was a generalization of the pi-statistic and that the Kappa came out of criticism to pi i got confused. If you could suggest an R function that could do it I would also appreciate.

Thank you.