# How to show that the condition of one hand predicts the condition of the other hand

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, categorical-data, paired-comparisons

I have this kind of data:

```
subject    hand    condition
s01        left    1
s01        right   0
s02        left    2
s02        right   2
..         ..      ..
```

The condition is a variable that gets values between $0$ and $5$ and indicates severity of a certain medical diagnosis.

I would like to show that if there is a problem with the left hand then there is likely a problem with the right hand, too. In other words, I want to show that there is some kind of dependence between the conditions of the different hands.

What kind of statistical test can I use here? I guess it is some kind of paired test I am looking for?

Comment: Do you really want to predict the *right* hand as a function of the *left* hand, or do you just want to see if the two hands are correlated?

Comment: Just to see if the hands are correlated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply reorganize your data so that each subject is in their own row (so-called 'wide-form') with the first column indicating the severity rating for their left hand and the second column indicating their right hand.  For example:

```
           left    right   
s01        1       0
s02        2       2
..         ..      ..
```

Then you can simply correlate the two columns / variables.  Since your data are ordinal ratings, you could use the [Spearman rank correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient).  (There are several other [rank correlations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_correlation) you could use, but that is probably the simplest and most conventional.)  Your observed Spearman's rho can be tested against $\rho=0$ (no association).  In fact, standard statistical software should output the test automatically.

Comment: The Spearman rank correlation coefficient came out to be about $0.8$ for my data :) The sample size is near 20,000, so I can make a strong conclusion. Thank you sir!

Comment: You're welcome, @med. .8 is a strong association & would be significant even w/ fairly small N.

Answer (score 0):

A way to measure this may be the intraclass correlation, which is the proportion of the total variance of the outcome that is explained by the common identifier (here, `subject`). In your problem, things are complicated by the condition being a categorical rather than a continuous variable. So what I would do is to fit a multilevel/mixed model with an ordinal probit link, say, and compute ICC as variance of the random effects / (variance of the random effects + variance of the residuals) where the latter variance is one for the probit link.

More discussion can probably be found [in this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3539/5739).

Comment: I can't judge how this answer stands compared to what was suggested by @gung but it sounds too difficult for my level. Hence, I accepted the other answer.

Comment: No problem. I think @gung's answer points to the same idea, basically, although differently executed.