# Difference Cohen's $\kappa$ and Spearman's $\rho$

Tags: correlation, association-measure

What is the difference between Cohen's $\kappa$ and Spearman's $\rho$?

Comment: Welcome to CV! I wonder if this question [essentially duplicates this one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3539/22228)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cohen's $\kappa$ can only be used for qualitative variables, whereas Spearman's $\rho$ can be generalized to both qualitative and quantitative variables.  It also seems like Spearman's $\rho$ has a defined and frequently-used hypothesis test associated with it (using the Fisher transformation, $\rho$ will be approximately Normally distributed) whereas Cohen's $\kappa$ appears to have some problems/hesitation associated with it.